# Best small distro for ROM burning of the system for an embedded system

Tags: memory, embedded, small-distribution

I am building a specific device and I would like to know what Linux based small distribution would be good when I would choose the put-Linux-on-the-ROM route, so, that the system is not possible to change on that device I am building, unless, of course, you physically replace the ROM or bypass it etc. which is beyond my control anyway.

I would like to hear from you what Linux distributions (preferably something small with a decent hardware support) is available for putting on the ROM module. Thank you.

Comment: Such things usually built by hand and crafted specially if you _really_ want it to fit well into your device. Otherwise, many systems such as Open/DDWRT exist today for routers, maybe Buildroot will fit your needs. If you just want to get a small thing that will fit well into 2M (for example) flash, you still will have to craft it yourself. Consider also to look at my works: https://github.com/siblynx/r2, it's just a generic thing that fits well into router, fast bootup and simple layout. You will still need a separate kernel for your device though.

Comment: And you also did not name your needs: do you need things like X11, GUIs, GL and Web engines? What kind of device do you build?